# Fast public transport from Kusatsu to Jigokudani Monkey Park during winter?

Tags: public-transport, japan, japan-rail

[Kusatsu](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kusatsu) and the [Jigokudani Monkey Park (Yamanouchi)](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yamanouchi) are only 46 kilometers away by road, but Google Maps only [suggests](http://goo.gl/maps/I8B3t) taking the Shinkansen all around the Kagonotoyama mountain, taking 4.5 hours and 7000 JPY.

Is there a faster way to go, and maybe less expensive?

It is in February, and I am not sure whether the direct route between the two (in yellow on the map) is open.

[image: Kusatsu - Yamanouchi] [image]

Comment: Seems to depend on the volcanos http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294232-i525-k7748928-Kusatsu_Onsen_to_Jigokudani_Monkey_Park_how_to_get_there-Japan.html

Answer (score 3):

I have sent an email to the tourist office, and they replied:

- The direct road is not accessible by car until April the 24th. A not-so-big detour via Ueda is the best (see screenshot below).
- By public transport, the best is to take the [bus from Kusatsu to Karuizawa](http://www.kusatsu-onsen.ne.jp/access/train03.php), then the normal train from [Karuizawa](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Karuizawa) to [Nagano](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nagano) and [Yudanaka](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yamanouchi).

> 草津から地獄谷野猿公苑に向かう、国道２９２号線の一部は、
>
> ４月２４日まで閉鎖されております。
>
> お車で行かれるとすると、
>
> 国道２９２号線を南へ降り、１４４号線を通り、
>
> 上田菅平インターチェンジから、高速道路をご利用頂く方法になります。
>
> （詳しくは、Attachmentをご覧ください。）
>
> （※この時期は雪が多く、道路にもたくさん雪があります。ご注意ください。）
>
> また、お車以外の方法で行かれる場合、
>
> 高崎駅まで戻る必要はありません。
>
> 草津温泉から軽井沢駅までバス、
>
> http://www.kusatsu-onsen.ne.jp/access/train03.php
>
> 軽井沢駅から長野駅まで、新幹線か普通列車を、
>
> 長野駅から、湯田中駅まで長野電鉄をご利用下さい。
>
> 軽井沢駅から、湯田中駅までの列車の詳細は下記のtrain route finder "Jordan"
>
> をご利用下さい。
>
> http://www.jorudan.co.jp/english/
>
> 湯田中駅から上林温泉まではバスかタクシーをご利用下さい。
>
> その後は、地獄谷野猿公苑まで歩いて約20分（約2km）だそうです。
>
> 詳細は↓こちら↓です。
>
> http://www.shibuonsen.net/yaenkoen/

[image: navitime]

Answer (score 2):

There is [a bus that runs between the two](http://www.kusatsu-onsen.ne.jp/access/bus03.php) from Shirone Kazan (白根火山) which is right next to Kusatsu to Yudanaka (湯田中) for 1500 yen and only takes 80 minutes (barring traffic jams).  From Yudanaka you can walk to Jigokudani in about 30 minutes or so.

However this website hasn't been updated since November and it sounds like the schedule may have changed then so it may be a good idea to email the people who run this website (the Kusatsu Onsen Tourism Bureau) and ask.

If the bus isn't running and you can rent a car that is the best bet, as it will get your to Jigokudani much quicker.

Comment: This website says the the bus only runs from April 25th to November 3rd unfortunately, so it can't be used (my question is about winter season)

Comment: It is probably worth it to email the Kusatsu Tourism Bureau and see if the bus doesn't run during Winter or whether it runs with a different schedule (and has not been updated).  If it doesn't run, they can probably give you the best recommendation for how to get there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I sent them an email and they replied with great info :-)